# Adding hashValues together using Bitwise XOR Operator or simply adding them together

Tags: swift, hash, bitwise-operators

I want to create a an unique identifier of a few properties in my class using:

```
class Foo {
    var name = "John"
    var array = ["string1", "string2"]

    var check: Bool { return name.isEmpty }

    var xor: Int { return name.hashValue ^ check.hashValue }
    var add: Int { return name.hashValue + check.hashValue }
}

let test = Foo()

print(test.xor) // prints 4799450059756749538
print(test.add) // prints 4799450059756749538
```

Working without problems.

But while reading some tutorials, some sites uses the operator `^` to "add" the hash values together.

My question is, does it have any (negative) effect if I use the operator `^` to calculate the `identifier`? Because when I calculate the hash value of the array, I can't use the operator `+` and I'm forced to use `^` instead (unless I use an `Int32`/`Int64` instead):

```
var identifier: Int { return name.hashValue ^ array.map { $0.hashValue }.reduce(0) { $0 ^ $1 } ^ check.hashValue }
```

Also I've seen people using bitwise left and right shift operators when handling hash values. Is there a particular reason for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason to use `^` (*bitwise exclusive-OR*) over `+` is that `+` can overflow and crash your app.

The reason to use bitwise left and right shift operators is to generate different hash values if the array order is different.  If you just `^` the hash values without shifting, then `["a", "b"]` and `["b", "a"]` would generate the same hash value.